# Counting the children matching grandchildren conditions in a single Django query

Tags: django, django-annotate, django-aggregation

Given the following models:

```
class Flight:

class Checklist:
    flight = ForeignKey(Flight)

class Item:
    checklist = ForeignKey(Checklist)
    completed = BooleanField()
```

I need to get the number of completed checklists for each flight. A checklist is considered completed when all of its items are completed.

I know for checklists I can do

```
Checklist.objects.annotate(
    is_complete=~Exists(Item.objects.filter(
        completed=False, 
        checklist_id=OuterRef('pk'),
    ))
)
```

but I need something for flights, ideally a single query. Something like

```
Flight.objects.annotate(
    completed_checklists=Count(
        Checklist.objects.annotate(<is complete annotation here>).filter(is_complete=True)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's the most efficient way but you can count the total number of checklists and subtract the number of checklists that have at least one incomplete item

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q, F

Flight.objects.annotate(
    checklist_count=Count('checklist', distinct=True),
    incomplete_checklists=Count('checklist', filter=Q(checklist__item__completed=False), distinct=True)
).annotate(
    completed_checklists=F('checklist_count') - F('incomplete_checklists')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function in the models something like the below:

```
    def get_total(self):
        #start with a zero total
        total = 0
        #check for all the checklist in item
        for b in self.checklist.all():
        #if there is a checklist that is completed add 1
        if self.completed:
            total += 1
        return total
```

You can then use `get_total`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to get it all in one query.